# swift Dismiss ViewController from a helper / another class

Tags: ios, swift, controller, parameter-passing, helper

I have a problem when i try to dismiss a view from a function of a helperClass instanced in the viewer class

```
public func set(playerController: AVPlayerViewController){
playerController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

how can I pass correctly the controller so the helper class can dismiss it?

Viewerclass:

```
helper.add(player: player)
helper.set(playerController: playerController)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just do `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` from the presented view controller, as Apple libraries handle the dismissal both from presenter and the presented view controllers. No need to pass a reference

Answer (score 1):

You also can give a callback to dismiss
something like this:

```
helper.add(player: player) {
 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

Player:
public func set(playerController: AVPlayerViewController, completion: (Void)->Void){
   completion()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this from your helper class:-

```
AppDelegate.sharedInstance().window?.topMostController()?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And add this function in your AppDelegate file :-

```
class func sharedInstance() -> AppDelegate{
   return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
}
```